# C вылет программы при попытке получить число из файла

Tags: c, файлы

Суть задачи - в файле находятся положительные и отрицательные числа. Все отрицательные нужно заменить нулём.
Было придумано следующее решение:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void open_file(char *arg,FILE *addr1,FILE *addr2){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    addr1=fopen(arg,"r+"); addr2=fopen("buf.txt","w+");
    printf("1\n");
    if(addr1==NULL){
        printf("Не могу открыть файл %s\n, проверьте аргумент", arg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void transform(FILE *addr1,FILE *addr2){
    int res,x;
    printf("1\n"); 
    for(;;){
        res=fscanf(addr1,"%d",&x);
        printf("1\n");
        if(res<=0) break;
        if(x<0) x=0;
        fprintf(addr2,"%d ",x);
    }
    printf("1\n");
    while (res>0){
        fscanf(addr2,"%d",&x);
        fprintf(addr1,"%d \n ",x);
    }
    printf("1\n");
}


void close_file(FILE *addr1,FILE *addr2){
    fclose(addr1);
    fclose(addr2);
    remove("buf.txt");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS"); 
    if (argc!=2){  
        printf("Некорректное число аргументов"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
    FILE addr1, addr2;
    open_file(argv[1],&addr1,&addr2);
    transform(&addr1,&addr2);
    close_file(&addr1,&addr2);
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в строчке `fscanf(addr1,"%d",&x);` программа вылетает. По синтаксису вроде проблем нет, компилятор тоже не ругается. В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не верное открытие файлов: в `open_file()`: указатели передаются по значению и открытые файлы не возвращаются обратно в `main()`. В итоге `addr1` и `addr2` оказываются не инициализированными.

Если не менять подход, то необходимо передавать в `open_file()` указатель на указатель и работать с ним соответственно:

```
void open_file(char *arg, FILE **addr1,FILE **addr2){
    // ...
    *addr1=fopen(arg,"r+"); *addr2=fopen("buf.txt","w+");
// ...

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    // ...
    FILE *addr1, *addr2;
    open_file(argv[1],&addr1,&addr2);
```

Альтернативным решением будет создать структуру, завернуть указатели на потоки в неё и передавать в функции уже указатель на оную.

Comment: переделал с вашими правками - отказывается компилироваться: _lvalue required as left operand of assignment_. Dev-C++, TDM-GCC 4.9.2, если что

Comment: @WhiskeyMotel, мой косяк — попутал разыменование со взятием адреса; подправил...

Comment: большое спасибо, заработало! 2 недели голову ломал :D